# Check if an address exist on a ethereum contract in a Joint account in a bank?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have to make a smart contract that will work similar to a normal bank . I have to do [Joint account](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&hs=DXd&channel=fs&dcr=0&ei=VzCyWuuxDMnbvgSU6p2oCw&q=joint%20account%20meaning%20&oq=joint%20account%20mening%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1l2.1411.4425.0.4482.8.6.0.0.0.0.198.346.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.2.345...0j0i67k1.0._xU7xJPZsPo)  registration . so , how i am taking two address as input , how do I check whether the user exists or not ?? What i was trying to do is combine both the addresses i.e.`_address1+_address2` and check if this user exists , but since i am unable to do that . can anyone tell me as to how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you want to track accounts by the combination of two addresses.

`keccak256(address1, address2)` would make sense, but be careful about the order of the addresses. If order isn't meaningful—(address1, address2) is equivalent to (address2, address1)—then you should sort the addresses first.

Comment: thanks a lot @smarx , it worked . But there is one more issue , when i am making the account with only one user , i.e. `_address2 = 0x0` , I am able to store some balance in it ( I have defined a struct which has a field for balance ) , but when `_address2 != 0x0` , whatever value i am initializing  to balance it gives 0 value . can you help me out ?